# Is this a good way to regulate fps?

Tags: sdl

In all of my tests I always regulate the fps by using this method.

```
const int fps = 30;
const int msPerFrame = 1000/fps; // 33 ms per frame, so it's more like 30.3030 fps
while(true)
{
  const int start = SDL_GetTicks();

  // do stuff

  const int end = SDL_GetTicks();
  const int delay = msPerFrame - ( end - start );
  if ( delay > 0 )
    SDL_Delay( delay );
  else
    std::cout << 
      "Warning, main loop took " << -delay << 
      " ms more than it was allowed." << std::endl;
}
```

At the beginning of the game while loop I set a start = SDL_GetTicks(); then I do various game logic followed by rendering and then finish it with end = SDL_GetTicks(). Finally, I do the regulation by this: delay = 1000/fps - (end - start); then call the SDL_Delay(delay); if it was greater than zero.

My question is, is this actually doing what I want or is there the possibility that there might be fluctuations? I got to wondering this because sometimes the smallest drawing functions make my cpu usage go up.

Comment: [Fix your timestep!](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/)

Comment: While that is a very good read, it is actually far too intelligent for me. :p  I'm not asking for another way, I'm just wondering if my code will work as your generic average programmer would do.

Comment: The methods described in the article I posted *are* what the generic average game programmer would choose from depending on requirements (I prefer the "Free the physics" method, because it makes it unnecessary to remember to keep the delta-time into account for every single calculation which greatily simplifies the code of the update function, but that's just my personal preference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.
SDL_Delay has a granularity of 10ms so it's not suitable for a game loop.
It's simple to test: use  SDL_GetPerformanceCounter() & SDL_GetPerformanceFrequency() to mesure the time taken by SDL_Delay(1) and you'll see it took 10ms.

In general, get used to measuring the effects of your code.

Comment: Maybe using c++11's std::chrono and std::this_thread::sleep_until could improve this condition!